# How do you handle Prettier settings in a large comany?

Tags: github, eslint, prettier

I have been a freelancer for a very long time until recently when I was hired on to a large team at an even larger company.

While I was a freelancer I could use whatever Prettier/ESLint settings I wanted because I was doing most if not all the pushes to the repo.

Now that I am working on this team, the Prettier/ESLint settings I have come to love cause havoc in the comany repo.

As far as I am aware my new team does not have a policy for this.

Is there a solution for this?  I have simply disabled Prettier in mt editor.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, it doesn't matter what style you pick as long as the project picks one and sticks with it.  If your language community prefers a certain one, then that's ideal; otherwise, a general company standard is fine.  Ideally this is done with a fixed tool, but it can be specified in documentation as well.

For example, if you're using Rust, use `rustfmt`, because that's what everybody uses.  I don't personally love all of the style choices that it makes, but it's more important that everyone agrees on *some* set of standards, and that's by far the most common option in Rust.  I have in past jobs ruthlessly enforced our company's preferred style even when it was not my preferred style because it made it easier for everyone to do the same thing.

If your project doesn't have a fixed tool and configuration, don't auto-format the code.  Git, for example, has style policies, but there's no approved automated tool, so formatting things with a tool (e.g., `clang-format`) anyway just causes diff noise.  You may propose an automated tool and settings, but if the project isn't in agreement, it's better to just format things by hand.  You *could* suggest an [`.editorconfig` file](https://editorconfig.org/) to make it easier for users' editors to do the right thing, however.

Answer (score 2):

Prettier and ESLint must be configured on the project level, not in the editor. In the project root, there should be configuration files for both Prettier and ESLint. When the Prettier editor extension finds a local configuration file, it ignores its global settings and uses the local ones from that file. It's enough to create an empty config file for Prettier to use its default recommended settings:

```sh
echo {}> .prettierrc.json
```

Also it's important that everybody in the team should use the same versions of these tools, so make sure the versions are pinned in `package.json` - e.g. `"prettier": "2.2.1"`, not `"prettier": "^2.2.1"`. When the Prettier editor extension finds a locally installed version, it uses it instead of the one shipped with the extension. Finally, don't forget about `eslint-config-prettier`. It must be used so that Prettier and ESLint don't conflict with each other.